# How to cancel by timeout StreamSocket in C# Universal WIndows App?

Tags: c#, sockets, concurrency

I tried using `CancellationTokenSource` but the timeout doesn't look like being called. Here is my code

```
        try
        {
            CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            tokenSource.CancelAfter(1000);
            HostName server = new HostName("rpi123");
            StreamSocket socketTester = new StreamSocket();
            await socketTester.ConnectAsync(server, ServerPort).AsTask(tokenSource.Token);
            return true;
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ERROR " + e.Data);
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine here ... how do you know it is not connecting?

C.

[Feel free to delete, cannot post comments]

Comment: I am expecting the catch exception block to be called if the hostname `rpi123` is not present in the network but it is not called. btw how do you know the task is cancelled by timeout?

Comment: I tested with a non-existing host and got the error in the debug console (visual studio), as expected, after approx. 1200 ms (saying that the task was cancelled). If I put a longer timeout, the exception says that host could not be found... SO all is well.

Comment: hmm weirdly, today I checked it again and now it's cancelling. hmm. thanks for the confirmation mate though :)